# KnpMenu: add attribute to MenuItem class

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I am using KnpMenu with Symfony2.3 through the KnpMenuBundle.

I would like to customize the class `MenuItem` by adding an attribute, the simplest way.

The aim is to be able to link any `MenuItem` to one of my application's entity, and to retrieve it afterwards.

For example, I want to do this:

```
$menu = $factory->createItem('root');
$menu->addChild('New Model', array('route' => 'my_route'))
     ->setAttribute('icon', 'glyphicon-plus')
     ->setRelatedEntity($myEntity);   // <== This doesn't exist by default
```

The easy but ugly way would be to edit `Knp\Menu\MenuItem.php` and add this:

```
/**
 * Entity to which this menuItem is related
 * @var Entity
 */
private $relatedEntity;

/**
 * Set relatedEntity
 *
 * @param string $relatedEntity
 * @return MenuItem
 */
public function setRelatedEntity($relatedEntity) {
    $this->relatedEntity = $relatedEntity;    
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get relatedEntity
 * @return Entity 
 */
public function getRelatedEntity() {
    return $this->relatedEntity;
}
```

I know it isn't the proper way to do it so I tried to override `Knp\Menu\MenuItem` and then `Knp\Menu\MenuFactory` but it is not enough...

I have the feeling I have to override a lot more things, so here I come to ask advice. The bundle is quite complex and I have the feeling that this functionnality (adding class attribute to MenuItem) is already managed by the bundle, although I don't understand how.

Any idea?

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21312804/1354222

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render custom attribute KNP Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301710/render-custom-attribute-knp-menu)